# Expose port of AWS EC2 instance to entire network

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, containers, port

I have an app which is deployed via Docker on one of our legacy servers and want to deploy it on AWS.  All instances reside on the company's private network.  Private IP addresses:

```
My local machine: 10.0.2.15
EC2 instance:     10.110.208.142
```

If I run `nmap 10.110.208.142` from within the Docker container, I see port 443 is open as intended.  But I if run that command from another computer on the network, e.g. from my local machine, I see that port is closed.

**How do I open that port to the rest of the network?**  In the EC2 instance, I've tried:

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT`

and it does not resolve the issue.  I've also allowed the appropriate inbound connections on port 443 in my AWS security groups (screenshot below):

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Include your security group details with your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley Updated.  Happy to provide more info if needed.

Comment: Your first HTTPS rule is invalid. 10.0.0.0/8 is not valid in AWS. The largest CIDR is /16. Change to 10.0.0.0/16. This should actually match the VPC CIDR. For the HTTPS IPv6 rule, note that this opens your server to the world over IPv6. Unless you plan to support public IPv6 I would delete that entry.

Comment: @JohnHanley I deleted the IPv6 entry (it was added by default).  I changed the CIDR to /16 and still does not work.  The reason I used /8 in the first place was because that was needed to allow me to connect to an RDS instance.

Comment: What is the private IP address of this EC2 instances and what is the private IP address of the instance that you are connecting from? For your nmap command are you specifying the private IP or the public IP? Note: Private IP addresses are safe to publish on the Internet.

Comment: Have made any changes to the default rules for your NACL?

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried connecting from two computers on our network (10.0.2.15 and 10.3.31.187).  The EC2 instance's private IP address is 10.110.208.142.  I used nmap on the private IP address: `nmap 10.110.208.142`.  Unsure if relevant, but today I had to append `-Pn` to that command to see the same output as yesterday.  I don't know what NACL is.

Comment: When you say "on our network" are you meaning your company''s network trying to connect to computers in your AWS network? Please update your question with more details on exactly what you are trying to do and the addresses of everything.

Comment: @JohnHanley I updated the question.  Sorry for the confusion, but I thought the AWS instance is on our network.  Basically, I don't see port 443 open on the EC2 instance when I run nmap from any other computer on the company network.  But I do see it open from a docker container deployed from the EC2 instance.

Comment: I created an answer based upon your last comment and information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  I'm using nginx and nginx failed to start, which explains why port 443 appeared to be closed.

In my particular case, nginx failed because I was missing the proper ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access EC2 instances in your AWS VPC network from your network outside of AWS using private IP addresses of the EC2 instances using the public Internet. This is why EC2 instances can have two types of IP addresses: Public and Private.

If you setup a VPN from your corporate network to your VPC then you will be able to access EC2 instances using private IP addresses. Your network and the AWS VPC network cannot have overlapping networks (at least not without fancier configurations).

You can also assign a public IP address (which can change on stop / restart) or add an Elastic IP address to your EC2 instances and then access them over the public Internet.

In either solution you will also need to configure your security groups to allow access over the desired ports.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not trying to access the EC2 instances from the public internet, only from the private company network.

Comment: However, you are trying to access the AWS servers using the EC2 instance private IP address. You need to use the EC2 instance Public IP address.

Comment: I created a new EC2 instance with public access and it still does not work.  `nmap <EC2 public ip address>` does not return any results when I run that command from a computer on the company network or even from the Docker container.

Comment: I found the issue, in case you're curious.  See my answer